# Sharekit Error on login face

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios6, sharekit

While trying with Sharekit in my application after login it is showing the following Msg "ERROR:this point has been deprecated."[image]

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

open your app in facebook "http://developers.facebook.com/"

Then go to apps>>your app >> setting >>Edit settings>> Advanced>>Migrations>>Disable all Breaking Changed

Comment: If your problem not solve then download latest sharekit from github.& then add in your app & check...

Comment: Can yu pls give me the latest link of sharekit